# Python Post Requests using Requests library giving broken pipe error

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, post, python-requests

I am running a API developed in GOLang which accepts post requests over LAN. My client is using Python to send some data (size 350KB) to the server. The python code is multithreaded and may be performing simultaneous post requests, 1 per each thread. Expected average requests per second between client and server is around 3. The requests are not getting timeout as the error gets raised much earlier.

I can not seem to find the source of the error. The network should be robust as both server and client are on a single switch having 1 Gbps. Please help.

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.1.105', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /match (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 32] Broken pipe)
```

Comment: That's propably an issue with the server

Comment: @t.m.adam Not a server issue. I have done load testing with much higher load. It works fine. Surprisingly the same code with multi threaded works fine in a sample script with just multiple calls with same load. But when I introduce it with my main code it gets broken error quite often (almost 40% of the total requests). In my actual script I doing some heavy processing in parallel threads. Not sure if that is the issue.

Comment: Hi @kafan1986 have you managed to find a solution for this problem?